# Cassandra Partition and Cluster Keys to Store Inverted index

Tags: cassandra, inverted-index

I need to use Cassandra to store an inverted index, in which words and their frequencies in articles are stored as follows:

```
word, article_title, frequency
```

Number of unique words is about 40M and number of Cassandra nodes = 2.
Which is better to use the first character of the word as Partition key or the word itself?
what about the Primary key?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the query that the table will serve.

Comment: The query would be like: select * from inverted_index which word in (word1, word2, ...);

Comment: Have you looked at sasi indexes?

Comment: I just looked at them. Actually I don't think I need to create indexes

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: With regards to your query, I would definitely say to use the word as the partition key.

If you would use only the first character, you will have only 26 partitions. You do not want that, if anything else, you will get hot-spotting. Some rows will be pretty short, since there are not a lot of words starting with a specific letter, and others will be very, very long, maybe even beyond the point it is performant to use. Yes, Cassandra has a two billion column per row limit, but the recommendation is to keep the size of the row in the millions. You also do not want to access all the words starting with 'A' if you want only 'AIRPORT'.

You need a high carnality, as random as possible, partition key so that the rows are easily dispersed throughout the cluster. On the other hand, it has to reflect your access patterns. In your case, you wan't to see stats for a word or set of words. Accessing by partition/primary is basically as fast as it gets with Cassandra.

As for the clustering key, it is more or less obvious, you can use the article title, OR, what I would do is actually use an article identifier (a UUID or such) as the cluster key. Article titles might change (typo?), and you certainly do not want to iterate through all your rows changing the title.